# How can i make a hidden html table for exporting?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I already have the code for exporting a html table to excel, but how can I **hide** the table and still access it with javascript?

```
<div id="dataExportDiv" style="display:none">
   <table>
      ...table data here...
   </table>
</div>
```

But the resulting excel document doesn't have any data. I've tried exporting without hiding the table and it works, so I know the export javascript is valid.

Comment: Perhaps it's the missing " on your id? Just ruling out possibilities before committing too much thought.

Comment: whoops. forgot to close it in the example.

Comment: Hmm... if it exports when not `display:block;` but doesn't with `display:none;` then I would suggest a simple CSS trick to move the table way far off the side of the screen.  The same way you typically do with drop-down menus.  ie. `#dataExportDiv{ position:absolute; left:-999em;`.  This will visual hide the DIV and it's contents but not actually hide it from what might be a 'feature' in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could display the table off screen (out of the viewport):

```
#parent {
  position: relative;
}
table {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
```

Beware that it'll still display if CSS are desactivated (obviously) and will be read by screen readers.
If you're displaying a chart, this table will be a good text alternative to them (with proper `th` and `scope="col|row"`) otherwise they'll find it a PITA if it's 3km long.
In the latter case, you can hide the table from most recent screen readers with the attribute `aria-hidden="true"` on `table` element and provide a skip link just before the table for older screen readers.

Comment: This works, although I added `top:-5000px` so it wouldnt add vertical space at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be missing a `"` after the `<div>`'s ID attribute value.

Comment: I made a mistake in the example. edited it now, though in my actual code it has it closed.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div style="display:none">
    <table id="tblID" style="display:block">
        ...table data here...
    </table>
</div>
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

**My Codes**

[image: My Codes]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).